# Hide superfluous ToolStripSeparator in Menu

Tags: c#, winforms, menu

I have a `ContextMenuStrip` control with several menu items A, B, C, D, E and separators before and after the item C.

[image]

During runtime, I decide dynamically in the `Opening` event whether to show the menu item C based on some conditions.

```
private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    toolStripMenuItemC.Visible = SomeCondition;
}
```

When the menu is shown at runtime and the item C is hidden, nevertheless, both separators are visible, which looks ugly.

[image]

Is there some built-in mechanism to automatically have multiple consecutive menu separators be combined into a single one? For example, the VCL framework in Delphi has the [`TPopupMenu.AutoLineReduction`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.Menus.TPopupMenu.AutoLineReduction) property for that.

---

It is certainly possible to write specific logic for the menu to look at what menu items are visible and then decide which separators to show. But the more items there are and the more separators there are, the more complex this code will become. And the code would have to be updated each time a menu item is added, removed or moved in the menu.

I am looking for a general way to use on any menu which works without knowing the specific items in the menu. I would prefer some way that is already included in WinForms out of the box, but you can also answer with your own tool function to clean up separators in menus.

Comment: `toolStripSeperator1.Visible =  SomeCondition;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because I haven't found a built-in way to do that in WinForms, I wrote this utility function:

```
public static class ToolStripExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Automatically show/hide separator in toolstrips (Menus, toolbars, etc).
    /// This will hide / show separators based on the other toolstripitems in the collections.
    /// A separator will be hidden if it would be the first visible entry in the list.
    /// A separator will be hidden if it would be the last visible entry in the list.
    /// A separator will be hidden if it would appear right after another separator.
    /// All other separatos will be shown.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="items">A collection of ToolStripItems</param>
    /// <param name="includeSubmenus">If true, also cleanup separators in submenus</param>
    public static void CleanUpSeparators(this ToolStripItemCollection items, bool includeSubmenus = true)
    {
        // Will be true when we have last seen a visible item 
        // which is not a separator 
        bool canInsertSeparator = false;

        List<ToolStripSeparator> keepers = new List<ToolStripSeparator>();
        List<ToolStripSeparator> gonners = new List<ToolStripSeparator>();

        ToolStripSeparator lastSeparator = null;

        // Decide which separators should stay and which should go
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            ToolStripItem item = items[i];

            if (item is ToolStripSeparator)
            {
                if (canInsertSeparator)
                {
                    keepers.Add(item as ToolStripSeparator);
                    lastSeparator = item as ToolStripSeparator;
                    canInsertSeparator = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    gonners.Add(item as ToolStripSeparator);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // After seeing at least one visible item, we can add a new separator again
                if (item.Available)
                {
                    canInsertSeparator = true;
                }
            }

            // Recursion
            if (includeSubmenus && item is ToolStripDropDownItem)
            {
                (item as ToolStripDropDownItem).DropDownItems.CleanUpSeparators(true);
            }
        }

        if (!canInsertSeparator && lastSeparator != null)
        {
            // The last separator has no following visible other entries, 
            // so we don't want it
            gonners.Add(lastSeparator);
        }

        // Show and hide the separators
        // First show, then hide, because it is possible
        // a separator at the end of the menu is in both lists
        // and it should be hidden
        foreach (var separator in keepers)
        {
            separator.Visible = true;
        }
        foreach (var separator in gonners)
        {
            separator.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

It would be used like this:

```
private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    toolStripMenuItemC.Visible = SomeCondition;

    contextMenuStrip1.Items.CleanUpSeparators();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out, it works in a different way, showing or hiding a `ToolStripMenuItem` and the `ToolStripSeparator` based on the relative position of the `ToolStripMenuItem` to hide:

The `ToolStripSeparator`s are shown/hidden when:

1. The Menu is the last one and the preceding item is a `ToolStripSeparator`
2. The Menu is the first one and the following is a `ToolStripSeparator`
3. The Menu is preceded and followed by a `ToolStripSeparator`

Method call: `ShowHideMenuItem([ParentMenu], [ToolStripMenuItem], [true|false])`

```
ShowHideMenuItem(ToolStripMenuItem1, ToolStripMenuItem5, true);
```

---

```
private void ShowHideMenuItem(ToolStripMenuItem ParentMenu, ToolStripMenuItem MenuItem, bool ShowOrHide)
{
    if (!ParentMenu.HasDropDownItems) return;
    int itemIndex = ParentMenu.DropDownItems.IndexOf(MenuItem);

    if (ParentMenu.DropDownItems.Count > 1)
    {
        if (itemIndex == 0 &&
            ParentMenu.DropDownItems[itemIndex + 1].GetType() == typeof(ToolStripSeparator)) {
            ParentMenu.DropDownItems[itemIndex + 1].Visible = ShowOrHide;
        }
        else if (itemIndex == ParentMenu.DropDownItems.Count - 1 &&
                    ParentMenu.DropDownItems[itemIndex - 1].GetType() == typeof(ToolStripSeparator)) {
            ParentMenu.DropDownItems[itemIndex - 1].Visible = ShowOrHide;
        }
        else if (ParentMenu.DropDownItems[itemIndex + 1].GetType() == typeof(ToolStripSeparator) &&
                    ParentMenu.DropDownItems[itemIndex - 1].GetType() == typeof(ToolStripSeparator)) {
            ParentMenu.DropDownItems[itemIndex + 1].Visible = ShowOrHide;
            ParentMenu.DropDownItems[itemIndex - 1].Visible = ShowOrHide;
        }
    }
    MenuItem.Visible = ShowOrHide;
}
```

Comment: I don't like this answer. It doesn't do what I would expect it to do. 1. You have to call it manually for every menu item that you hide / show while I like a solution which you have to call only once at the end of Opening to cleanup the menu. 2. It doesn't correctly all cases. For example, in the situation shown in the question, both separators would be removed, leaving no separator between B and D which is expected behaviour. It can also not deal correctly with multiple menu items at the beginning or end of the menu being hidden and so on...

Comment: Well, that's why I posted it. It's a different method. If it did the same exact thing... The second point is just an option: `ParentMenu.DropDownItems[itemIndex - 1].Visible = ShowOrHide;` (or the opposite separator) can be removed, leaving one of the separators *alive*. The first point is a personal preference, nothing to add to it. It's easy to adapt, anyway.